# get current element using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: xpath, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to use Simple HTML DOM to find objects via XPath. 
It's working pretty well but I can't seem to get the current element:

```
$object->find('.');
$object->find('..');
$object->find('//');
```

all return an empty array

```
$object->innertext
```

returns a normal table with HTML, so the object IS valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple HTML DOM doesn't recognize '.' for getting the current element, 
in fact, it uses Regex to find elements using XPath. 
In order to solve this problem I used [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) instead of Simple HTML DOM, 
which has a lot more options and functionality.